# createElement vs. createElementWithClass

Tags: javascript

I am working with this script to generate a table of contents:

https://github.com/nanotube/generated_toc

I'm using it on this test page. As you can see, the [back to top] link that is created is really ugly:

http://www.utahrails.net/up/up-loco-features_toc-test.php

To apply a CSS style to the "[back to top]" link, the div that is created needs to have a class.

This works:

```
  // create a "back to top" link
  if (back_to_top == 'on'){
    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href='#beforetoc'>[back to top]</a>";
    this_head_el.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, this_head_el.nextSibling);
```

But this does not. The contents in the ToC disappears, and all the links disappear:

```
  // create a "back to top" link
  if (back_to_top == 'on'){
    newdiv = document.createElementWithClass('div', 'back-to-top');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href='#beforetoc'>[back to top]</a>";
    this_head_el.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, this_head_el.nextSibling);
```

I'm really new to scripting, and I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: Why do you think there is a method named `createElementWithClass()`?

Comment: What does the JavaScript console show?

Comment: @jfriend: thank you for confirming that it doesn't exist. I was amazed that I'd missed such a useful function/method until now.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your answer. That fixed it. I'm learning so fast I think my head will explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reference for a `createElementWithClass()` method on the document object.  If you were checking your javascript error console or the debug console, it should have shown you the exact error.

Just use this:

```
// create a "back to top" link
  if (back_to_top == 'on'){
    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.className = "back-to-top";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href='#beforetoc'>[back to top]</a>";
    this_head_el.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, this_head_el.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Thanks. Basic stuff, but that's how we learn; do it wrong first.

Comment: Console? Console? What console? Oh, that console. (Firefox Tools>Web Developer>Web Console) Now I just need to figure out what it's telling me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (at least no native) `createElementWithClass` function. Use

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.className = 'back-to-top';
…
```

(see docs for [`className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) and [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var))